# primefaces dataExporter EL exception

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I can build with success the following `p:dataTable`:

```
<p:dataTable id="questionario" var="risp" value="#{domande.elencoRisposte}" >  
        <f:facet name="header">
                Questionario di #{userBean.nome} #{userBean.cognome}
        </f:facet>
        <p:column>    
                <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Domanda" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{domande.getDomanda(risp.domanda).testo}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Risposta" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{risp.testo}" />
        </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

but I get the exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'getDomanda' not found on type ispra.Questionario
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:229)
```

when I try to export the with the `p:dataExporter` component:

```
<h:commandLink>
    <p:graphicImage value="pdf.png" />
    <p:dataExporter type="pdf" target="questionario" fileName="questionario" />
</h:commandLink>
```

`domande` is the managed bean of type `ispra.Questionario`.

Any ideas?

code snippet:

```
@ManagedBean(name="domande") 
@SessionScoped 

public class Questionario { 
    private ArrayList<Domanda> elencoDomande; 
    private LinkedHashMap<String,Risposta> risposte; 

    ...

    public Domanda getDomanda(String codice) { 
        return setDomande.get(codice); 
    } 

    public ArrayList<Risposta> getElencoRisposte() { 
        return new ArrayList<Risposta>(this.risposte.values()); 
    }

    ...

}
```

`Risposta` Class has `testo` and `domanda` attributes; `Domanda` Class has `testo` atribute.

Comment: Can you post the managed bean? 
Is `getDomanda()` a method on the managed bean?
Also, which JSP container version are you using? Calling methods with parameters in the EL was introduces in JSP 2.2. Mabye this is a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a [bug in PrimeFaces](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4156) that they (for some reason) won't fix.
I suggest you use the [PrimeFaces Extensions exporter](http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-myfaces/views/exporter.jsf). This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

What is the getDomanda function doing? It looklike you put your Domanda object in and it returns an Domanda object?

Try this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{risp.domanda.testo}" />
```

And then the export function will work

Comment: getDomanda return an Domanda object, but the method signature is: `public Domanda getDomanda(String codice)`, so I need a call to get the String from risp first. I tried <h:outputText value="#{domande.domanda(risp.domanda).testo}" /> but doesn't work. As suggested by Jens I'll post the classes as soon as I can.